# linear time algorithm for mst given |E|=99+|V|

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I need to make a linear algorithm for finding minimal spanning tree given an undirected weighted and connected graph(with no isolated verities) the has |V| vertices and |V|+99 edges
I think the solution should be based on Kruskal and divide an concur but no luck till now, any ideas?

Comment: Possible hint: perhaps the trick here is to prove that one of the _standard_ approaches (Kruskal, Prim, Boruvka, ?..) works in linear time.

Comment: i tried to prove the (|V|+99)log|V|<=|V|+|V|+99
but its not true for every |V|

Comment: Yeah; so maybe try something other than Kruskal then...

Comment: For example, if it was true that the priority queue in Prim contains at most 99 elements at each moment, that would automatically mean linear time.

Comment: Even if not, the attempt in that direction can give some insight.

Answer (score 2):

First remove all vertexes of degree 1, and add their adjacent edges to the MST until there are no more vertexes of degree 1.

Then consider each chain of degree-2 vertices.  If a chain is a cycle, then add all but the most expensive edge to the MST.

Otherwise, the chain must run between two vertexes of degree >= 3.  Replace the chain with a single edge. The cost of this edge will be the cost of the most expensive edge in the chain.  That is the difference in cost between connecting the two ends via the chain instead of just connecting the vertexes to the ends.

Now you're left with vertexes of degree >=3.  There must be less than 200 of those, and less than 300 edges remaining.  Run Kruskal's to determine which edges go in the MST.

Comment: Can a cycle of degree-2 vertices actually exist here?

Comment: If it's the whole graph after removing the degree-1 vertexes (which, of course implies |E| < |V| + 99), then yes.  But I also wanted to allow for constructing a spanning forest of a disconnected graph.

Comment: Ok, so not for the given problem, right?

Comment: Well, sure... but that is expecting the OP to have been super careful with his problem statement, and they usually aren't.

Comment: About the last step: I think there can be more than 100 nodes. Like a cycle/circle of 198 nodes, plus 99 additional edges connecting each node with the node "on the opposite side of the circle.

Comment: yes, you're right. fixed

Comment: can you please elaborate?  how exactly did you know that the remaining edges are  less than 200? or 300 for that matter?

Comment: Each time we remove a vertex, we also remove an edge.  The remaining vertexes are degree >=3, which means that the number of edges remaining is at least 50% more than the remaining number of vertexes.  You can only have 99 more edges than vertexes, so that limits the number of vertexes to 200.

Comment: but if the number of vertices are 200 and all of them are of a degree 3 or more doesn't that mean that you have 100% more edges than vertices? 
given  E=V+99 this means v+99>=2v   so v is greater or equal to 33?

Comment: Each edge is shared by 2 vertices, so 200 vertices of degree 3 is 200 * 3 /2 = 300 edges.  That's 50% more than the number of vertices.